# Connecting to the database using php is not working with me.. Access denied for user 'ahmadham_ahmad'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I'm using cPanel.
I created a database and a user with it's password.
But when im trying to connect to it using this code

```
$con=mysqli_connect("ahmadhammoud.com", "ahmadham_ahmad", "***********", "ahmadham_dbtest"); if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();} mysqli_close($con);
```

I get

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'ahmadham_ahmad'@'206.72.199.253' (using password: YES) in /home/xyz/public_html/scratches/sql/1/index.php on line 3 Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'ahmadham_ahmad'@'some_ip_address' (using password: YES)Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/xyz/public_html/scratches/sql/1/index.php on line 10
```

Someone please help me.. is there something should be done in the settings of the cpanel or what :'\

Comment: It's seems that your username of database connection isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "ahmadham_ahmad", "***********", "ahmadham_dbtest"); if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();} mysqli_close($con);
```

Use `localhost` if you are on same server as your mysql server. Then try change your username, `ahmadham_ahmad` to `ahmadham`:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "ahmadham", "***********", "ahmadham_dbtest"); if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();} mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: the first one worked for the connection thanks.. 
but when im trying to get records from the table with for example "$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabletest");" it says

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/ahmadham/public_html/scratches/sql/1/index.php on line 5

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/ahmadham/public_html/scratches/sql/1/index.php on line 5

Comment: If you use connection `mysqli_connect()` you can't use `mysql_query()`. Both are not same! Please refer to manual for mysql improved instead of old classical way `mysql_query()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you didnt enable remote connection. try to enable remote connection i think then it should work.